# Entire string not being echoed?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to implement the functionality to delete a post on my site if you are the author. I have the part that authenticates whether or not you can delete it down, but my problem is when  it `echo`es the link to delete it.

```
<div id="postFull" class="postFull">
    <span class="postText"><?php echo stripslashes($text) ?></span><br /><br />
    <span class="metaInfo">...says <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $posterID ?>"><i><?php echo $poster ?></i></a> on <i><?php echo $date ?></i></span>
    <?php 
        if($deletable) 
            echo "<span style='align: right;'><a href='post.php?id=$postID&delete=true>Delete</a></span>";
    ?>
</div>
```

When I view the page, the delete link isn't showing up. After looking at the HTML source in Chrome, I can see that it echos `<span style='align: right;'>` but nothing after that. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have a problem with invalid HTML. The `href` attribute is missing a closing `'`, therefore the browser likely discards the entire element since it can't parse it correctly. Use View Source (the *raw* source) to confirm what is output, the Inspect Element view is already processed by the browser and does not necessarily represent what your script actually outputs.

Comment: Also there's no proper HTML escaping of output, `magic_quotes` is on, and he didn't escape an ampersand in his url.